# How Do I Create A HTML Select With Only Items In Database In Asp.Net Razor?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

*Short about the website: 
Website where users can log in to see the logs in our database and where admins can add new users and change the roles of the users in the database.*

On my "Register new users page" I add the users to a specific 'CustomerID' and I want the admin to only be able to select the 'CustomerID's which exist. In the HTML code you hopefully will be able to see what I want to do - but I don't really understand how to do it properly. Any ideas are apprechiated.

In short: How do I fill out my  with only 'CustomerId's that exist?

HTML Code:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<NowasteWebPortalMVC.Models.RegisterModel>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<select name="customerId">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <option>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerId)</option>
}
</select>
```

RegisterController.cs

```
public class RegisterController : Controller
{
    private UsersAndRolesDBContext db = new UsersAndRolesDBContext();

    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Portal";
        var CustomerIds = (from Users in db.UsersAndRoles
                           select Users);
        return View(CustomerIds.ToPagedList(1, 50));
    }
}
```

RegisterModel.cs

```
namespace asdMVC.Models
{
    [Table("UsersAndRoles")]
    public class RegisterModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    }
    public class UsersAndRolesDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public UsersAndRolesDBContext() : base("MySqlConnection")
        {

        }
        public DbSet<RegisterModel> UsersAndRoles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT:** Clarified text, made the page load again. But the select is **empty** now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML Code:**

```
@model WebPortalMVC.Models.RegisterModel
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedCustomerId)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCustomerId, Model.CustomerID)
```

**RegisterController.cs**

```
public class RegisterController : Controller
{
    private UsersAndRolesDBContext db = new UsersAndRolesDBContext();

    public ActionResult Register()
    {
         ViewBag.Title = "Portal";
        var model = new RegisterModel
        {
            CustomerID = GetCustomerIds()
        };
        return View(model);
}

public class DbCustomerIds
    {
        public List<DbCustomerId> GetCustomerIds()
        {
            List<DbCustomerId> Customers = new List<DbCustomerId>();
            string queryString = "SELECT Id, Name FROM dbo.Customers";
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlConnection"].ConnectionString);
            DataSet customers = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(customers, "Customers");

            foreach (DataRow item in customers.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                DbCustomerId cid = new DbCustomerId();
                cid.Id = Convert.ToInt32(item["Id"]);
                cid.Name = Convert.ToString(item["Name"]);
                Customers.Add(cid);
            }
            return Customers;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCustomerIds()
    {
        var DbCustomerIds = new DbCustomerIds();
        var customers = DbCustomerIds
                    .GetCustomerIds()
                    .Select(x =>
                            new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                                Text = x.Name
                            });

        return new SelectList(customers, "Value", "Text");
    }
```

**RegisterModel.cs**

```
namespace WebPortalMVC.Models
{
[Table("UsersAndRoles")]
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Customer ID")]
    public int SelectedCustomerId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CustomerID { get; set; }
}

public class DbCustomerId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UsersAndRolesDBContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersAndRolesDBContext() : base("MySqlConnection")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<RegisterModel> UsersAndRoles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to show a selectlist populated with customer details selected from the database.

The first thing to do is to add a `SelectList` property to your ViewModel. I'm not sure what the PagedList is doing - do you use it solely to populate the selectlist?  If so we don't need it.  Your new ViewModel would look something like this:

```
public class RegisterUserViewModel
{
    public SelectList UsersAsSelectList { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller you would populate the selectlist:

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
   ViewBag.Title = "Portal";
   var users = from u in db.UsersAndRoles
                       select new
                       {
                           u.Id, u.Name
                       };
   var model = new RegisterUserViewModel
   {
        UsersAsSelectList = new SelectList(users, "Id", "Name");
   }
   return View(model);
}
```

And your view:

```
@model RegisterUserViewModel

@Html.DropDownList("Users", @Model.UsersAsSelectList )
```

There are other ways to do this and I've kept things separate for the sake of clarity. It can certainly be refactored later but it should get you started.

Comment: Updated code - still giving an empty list. Any other ideas?

Comment: And to add to the explanation - What I want to do is to populate a selectlist with the customerId's that exist in the table only.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what my example does. Can you debug it and see where the problem is?

Comment: I run it, it loads the page with no errors, I click to select in the list - I get nothing. http://imgur.com/nNST1nS

Comment: Updated main post again to reflect and clarify the code I am running - following your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Stepwise:
1: Get all users from db
2: Create selectlistitems
3: Create dropdown with selectlist items

**1:**

```
public class RegisterUserViewModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> UsersSelectListItems { get; set; }
}



var users = from u in db.UsersAndRoles
    select new
    {
        u.Id, u.Name
    };
```

**2:**

```
var model = new RegisterUserViewModel
{
    UsersSelectListItems = users.Select(u => new SelectListItem{Value = u.Id.ToString(), Text = u.Name}).ToList();
}
```

**3:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("Users", Model.UsersSelectListItems)
```

Comment: So I need to create a new RegisterUserViewModel.cs and can't use the RegisterModel.cs that I have? I'm very new to this, sorry.

Comment: You can, but it's not good practise to use your EF-classes in views.